# Symfony : is there a best practice about the directories' name including traits and interfaces?

Tags: php, symfony, interface, traits

I guess I can't create a `Trait` or `Interface` directory inside my bundle since this is a keyword that would bring problems when used (i.e. `use MyBundle\trait\MyTrait`).

Is there a best practice about how to name these directories ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- [Symfony best practises](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html)
- [Symfony - Organizing Your Business Logic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html)
- [PSR coding standards](http://www.php-fig.org/)

Symfony specific: Put your traits in Util folder. In terms of the interfaces; e.g. you have a service class called Hello and HelloInterface then they both should go to Service folder or if you have some kind of class called Yow and YowInterface then you can put them Util folder as well. As simple as that.

Answer (score 4):

You can create it on many ways, but like John said there's not a specific one.

I would create them in a CoreBundle and not necessarily with Trait as a class name.
e.g. in my project we have them all created in

CoreBundle\Entity\Traits\ExampleEntity

Answer (score 3):

Regarding naming convention, see [coding standards](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html#naming-conventions)

Regarding directory structure, I don't specifically put them in a trait directory. It depends on how you want to organize your code. Generally, most people will put the trait inside a package folder for the behaviour it represents, i.e., Mysql\ConnectionTrait